# Data structure for Choice-Based Adventure Game?

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-structures, adventure

I'm designing a choice based adventure game in VB.NET 2010, where you are presented with a story label, and you choose between 2 buttons, which choice you want to make. I want to know the most efficient way to do this.

My goals are to store the labels for the buttons and the story in some form of data structure, which is temporarily a hash table right now, and some form of structure for the choices. Right now I am using a custom class that references the indexes of the next 2 choices and their respective label indexes which stores the class instances in a hashtable. I've looked into things like arrays, dictionaries, lists, and collections, but I'm not sure which one best fits what I'm after. Any .NET data structure would work. What is the most efficient data structure for these 2 pieces of data? Would just a string array work?

Comment: "Choice Based"? you mean like a *'Choose your own Adventure'*, or a *'Visual Novel'*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I'd define the structures (assuming by VB.Net-fu isn't failing me):

```
Public Class Decision
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property FirstChoice As Decision
    Public Property SecondChoice As Decision
End Class
```

The `Title` is what you display on or above the button to select that choice.

The `Description` is what you display once you've committed that choice, and are coming to the next decision.

If `FirstChoice` or `SecondChoice` is null, you can choose to hide the button.  This will allow you to make only one choice optional, and have it skewed to once side of the frame, for dramatic effect.  E.g.:

```
                  You've found yourself in a narrow corridor



                                                              [Go Right]
```

If you want to enable more choices than two, or at least leave yourself free to do so in the future, you could define your data structure like this:

```
Public Class Decision
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property Decisions As New List(Of Decision)
End Class
```

You could use a `ListBox` or `GridView` style control to display it to the user, or optionally switch between a list box and buttons depending on how many items you have in the list.

By the way, the data structure is intentionally recursive.  This becomes a tree structure, and at each node of the tree you have a decision, and potentially child decisions.

Normally you wouldn't loop such a structure, but there is no reason you couldn't in this case.  If you hit a "game over" style situation, your option can simply be to go back to the beginning, which will be linked to the root instance (and thus be a "cyclic graph").

**Edit**

Here's a code sample to show you how you can hook these together:

```
Dim darkAlley = New Decision With
{
    .Title = "Dark Alley",
    .Description = "You are in a deep dark alley." _
        + "  The night surrounds you and you feel a bit claustrophobic." _
        + "  Obvious exits are east and Salisbury street."
}

Dim eastOfDarkAlley = New Decision With
{
    .Title = "East of Dark Alley",
    .Description = "You are mauled by a bear!" _
        + "  He was a dire bear, so he had rabies.  Start over?"
}

Dim salisburyStreet = New Decision With
{
    .Title = "Salisbury street",
    .Description = "Mmm... Ground beef... Blarrghlhlap (*tongue hangs out*)"
}

darkAlley.FirstChoice = eastOfDarkAlley
darkAlley.SecondChoice = salisburyStreet

eastOfDarkAlley.FirstChoice = darkAlley

salisburyStreet.FirstChoice = darkAlley
```

Comment: My class right now holds indexes to a hashtable which has the "story" and the two decisions. I don't think your example would work in my context, I need to store: ChoiceID, ChoiceOneLabelID, ChoiceTwoLabelID, ChoiceOneID, and ChoiceTwoID. I just link the One and Two ID's to the "choiceID" of something else, so resembling some kind of hierarchy or "binary tree" but is this the best way to do it? Should I edit in my code?

Comment: @Marc: The hash table will work too, so only convert if you want to.  But you did ask for advice in this area.  A tree like this is more declarative, and doesn't rely on IDs (which really have nothing to do with your data).  It can easily use initialization syntax to build the whole tree at once, with no temp vars.  It is less likely to fit well in a SQL DB, but as far as I know that's not important.  You could use child labels instead of titles, as you suggest, but it will be just as easy either way.  If you go with the `List` option instead of two children, then you should go with a `Title`.

Comment: I don't need to store it in any type of persistent storage, but im just looking for the best key-value data structure. I just realized maybe what im after is a string array?

Comment: @Marc: That's my point.  If you're not using a DB, and not streaming over the wire, why would you use IDs?  They're only useful if you want to store or transmit data.  For in-memory objects, variables (local, member, static, part of another data structure, etc) work way better.  If you really *want* to use Ids, or have too much investment/momentum behind them in your project, then use a `Dictionary<string, string>` or `Dictionary<int, string>`.  They're made for looking up values from other values ("associative arrays").

Comment: I'm just trying to get everything referring to each other, I figured ID's would be easiest. So your saying store the actual member variables as the class?

Comment: Unless you've already gone through and given everything an ID, yeah.  Create a class that represents a "room" or "decision point" or whatever, make instances of them, and make them point at each other.  When you call `new` on the class, you can chain your calls to `new` so you don't have to make local variables for every single room.  Or you can give them all local variables if it feels right, and hook them up after you've created both "rooms" separately.  Maybe I should just add some code to the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your game is pretty clearly a decision tree.  If there are only ever 2 choices, some modified form of a binary tree would be perfect.  Otherwise, a somewhat more complicated n-ary tree would do it.

Comment: Yeah it's two choices, then the player makes 3 overall. So it branches out to 3 levels of choice, and the 8 endings. Which one would work then?

Comment: @MarcDiMillo I would look into binary trees.  I don't have experience with vb.net specifically, so I'm not sure exactly what that would entail.